# Slider component not re-rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I made a socket connected app, when a value is changed, all the other clients receive the value modification. This is supposed to lead into an automatic UI change.

Here is my code :

```
<View style={{marginTop:20}}>

     <Slider
        ref="container"
        minimumValue={0}
        maximumValue={100}
        value={this.state.briValue}
        onValueChange={val => {
             this.setState({ briValue: val })
             socketEmit('hue-bri', val)
         }
     }
     />

    <Text>Brightness : {this.state.briValue} %</Text>
</View>
```

The result :

[image]

Issue : the slider thumb does not move

I don't know why the `Slider` component does not re-render while the `Text` component does.

I tried to force the reload with `this.refs.container.forceUpdate()` but it does nothing.

I use the Slider from react-native-elements and the Text component is from the original react-native library.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`value` prop is only used to initialize the slider.
Ref : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/slider.html#value